# SQLite Trigger ( NOT TRIGGERING)

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers, insert

I created a SQLite Trigger that should execute when my reg_bttn onCLick is selected after data has already been inserted in the db. I get no compile error,no logcat errors, and no trigger prevent the new insert. My trigger statement is locate din my DB class. should it be in my class that does the insert.

```
  public LoginDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
        TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"

                    + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " text not null);";

        db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER DATABASE_NAME " +
                " BEFORE INSERT " +
                " ON "+TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS+ 
                " WHEN  BEGIN " +  
                " SELECT (( SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS + " WHERE "
                        + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + "' AND "+ COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD +") IS NOT NULL)" +
                        " THEN RAISE ( ABORT, 'ID ALREADY EXIST') END;" +
                        "END;");


           db.execSQL(sqlDataStore);
    }
```

insert:

```
      public void onClick (View v) {

    rUsername = rName.getText().toString();
    rPasscode = rCode.getText().toString();

    RegDetails regDetails = new RegDetails();
    regDetails.setrName(bundleRegName);
    regDetails.setpCode(bundleRegCode);
    if(v.getId()==R.id.rtn_button){
        finish();

    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.reg_button){
        insertCredentials(regDetails);
    }
}
    private void insertCredentials(RegDetails regDetails){

        LoginDB androidOpenDBHelper = new LoginDB(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = androidOpenDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME, rUsername);
        contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, rPasscode);

        long affectedColumnid = sqliteDB.insert(LoginDB.TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS, null, contentValues);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials Saved! Please login" + affectedColumnid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sqliteDB.close();
        finish();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a constraint: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: anybody landed here looking for SQLITE TRIGGER DEMO http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-sqlite-trigger-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with using counts in triggers versus checking for null.  For example:     (SELECT Count() FROM table WHERE new.xxx = table.xxx) == 0).